# What does the recitation at the beginning of this sukta say? (RV I.32)

Tags: rig-veda, indra

What does the recitation at the beginning of this sukta say?
Edit:
What does it say in the video, Before rishi, Chanda and devata?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUnywXQ6a5M

This is Rig Veda, mandala 1, sukta 32

Before the beginning of the sukta I recognize the following:

> hiraṇyastūpa āṅgirasa ṛṣiḥ |
>
> indro devatā |
>
> triṣṭup chandaḥ ||

and then the sukta starts:

> indra̍sya̱ nu vī̱ryā̍ṇi̱ pra vo̍ca̱ṃ yāni̍ ca̱kāra̍ pratha̱māni̍ va̱jrī ...

but I'm missing just the first part before the

> hiraṇyastūpa āṅgirasa ṛṣiḥ |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says:

> Indraschandeeti panchadasharscha suktasya..

I don't know what is the meaning of Indraschandeeti, but otherwise, it is simply stating the Viniyogah of the Mantra and is stating the name of the Vedic Sukta, recitation of which is about to be done..

The meaning of "panchadasharscha suktasya" simply is "for the Panchadasharcha sukta..."

For example, when we say " **Asya Sri X Mahamantrasya** A Rishi B Chandaha C Devata..." during Viniyogah of any Mantra, it means -- "For the great Mantra called X, A is the Rishi, B is the Chandaha and etc.."

Similarly, it's being done here.

Without the Indraschandeeti, the Viniyogah simply means" For the Panchadasharcha Sukta, Hiranyastupa is the Rishi, Indra is the Devata ..etc"

Comment: thanks, I'd like to be sure about "indrashcandeeti". It would be indraśca and diti (indraścanditi) ? or aditi? or something else?

Comment: @Indra I am not sure on that part..the rest is quite clear though.

Answer (score 4):

**What says ON THE VIDEO? Before rishi, Chanda and devata?**

[image]

As mentioned in the above screenshot, the words ***Indra*, *Panchdasharche Suktam*** (as it has [15 Richas](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01032.htm)) etc. are recited followed by Rishi and Chanda (meter).

---

Based on number of Richas these numbers are given, nothing to do with Sukta (Chapter) number. For example RV 1.31 has *Ashtadasharche Suktam* word as it has [18 Richas](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01031.htm):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know that. What I'm looking for is what is recited in the video just at the begining, before the rishi, Chanda and devata. I'm not understand the voice properly (it seems to say indrasya vritti something but not sure). I'll edit question to be more explicit. Thanks

Comment: @Indra Edited my answer...

Comment: thanks, in audio it says something more elaborate (maybe because sandhi etc), but seems more like the other answer, something like: " indraścānditi pañcadaśarca sūktasya " but, what may be "indraścānditi" ? Actually is it "indraścānditi" what it says?

Comment: by the way, good correction about richas. That was a very good way to ensure the proper continuity of oral tradition (and even writings) because saying the number of verses with sukta, you can check that don't forget anything

Comment: @Indra I believe those words are formed from Indra & Nichrid (related to writing style) & Panchdasha (number of Richas) & Suktam after using *Sandhi*, *Vibhakti* and other grammatical concepts...

Comment: do you mean nichrid meter? so should it be nicṛd triṣṭup chandas?